# VS 2022 17.1.3 Empty new class

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022

When adding a new class, it only creates it with namespace and without usings.
I had no such problem before in VS19. How can i fix it?
[image]

I tried to reinstall vs

Comment: .NET 6? This is likely because of the new [Implicit Usings](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/) feature. More [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) on this.

Comment: Im using .NET 5.0. I have the same problem in my older projects which I created in VS19

Comment: This is by design for `visual studio latest release` but if you would like to anable it you could do by enabling `CodeLens` you could get it  by navigating  **`Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages → CodeLens`**

Comment: I turned on CodeLens and it still creates the class without usings.

Comment: Try to add `new controller class` it would add   `using` block, but for `new class` it won't, because, your class doesn't use any additional refereces which need to add initially, in `Visual studio` lastest release for adding new class it won't add any `using block` since it doesn't has any reference to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As said, Try to add `new controller class` it would add   `using` block, but
> for `new class` it won't, because, your class doesn't use any
> additional refereces which need to add initially, in `Visual studio`
> lastest release for adding new class it won't add any `using block`
> since it doesn't has any reference to add.

**Note:** If you would just try it before `dotnet core 3.1` you would see that it would add `using` block. as below:

[image]

> Since `dotnet 5 and 6`compiler automatically adds a set of `using directives` based on the project type. You can [`get more information on official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#implicit-using-directives)

***`"When Adding Class which required class reference"`***

If you add other then your `self define class` for example `middleware class` or `startup` class it would add `using directives` as required. See the screenshot below:

[image]

> So hope you get the difference already. It’s not an issue, it’s a new
> features in `latest dotnet release` to redeem repetitive using
> directive monotonously.